# template parameters default value

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying my very first template. the following code compiles :

```
template<class T,class C=int> class MyClass
{};
```

But not this :

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
template<class T,class C=vector<T>> class MyClass
{};
```

Yet i see the standard vector class template declared like this :

```
template < class T, class Alloc=allocator<T> > class vector
{};
```

The errors the compiler throws are :

*error: spurious '>>', use '>' to terminate a template argument list
*error: definition of 'class MyClass' inside template parameter list
*error: two or more data types in declaration of 'type name'
*error: expected '>' before ';' token
*error: expected unqualified-id before ';' token

Comment: Perhaps you'd get use out of a compiler with better error messages. *error: a space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')* I also assume you knew about this one, but *error: no template named 'vector'; did you mean 'std::vector'?*

Comment: You might want to add `std::` before `vector`.

Comment: If you compile it as C++11, you should be able to use >> without the space.

Answer (score 2):

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f93734d989e10446

No, it works. You just forgot the `std` namespace.

Comment: @coucou8949 Don't do this. This causes headaches if library names collide.

Comment: @coucou8949 Yes. You should use `std::`.

Comment: i removed this "using namespace std;" and did as you said.still the same errors.

Comment: The linked site compiles it as C++14. If you're compiling as regular old C++98, you must write `std::vector<T> >` instead `std::vector<T>>`.

Comment: error: a space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >'). i think that's the problem.that's what the compiler should have thrown.someone should post a proper answer so i can make it the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

the code was :

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
template<class T,class C=vector<T>> class MyClass
{};
```

but i should have written :

```
#include <vector>

template<class T,class C=std::vector<T> > class MyClass//with space between right angle brackets  : '> >'
{};
```

Comment: The requirement for the space was removed in C++11 - consider using a more up-to-date compiler